# Java UI web frameworks

Tags: java, vaadin

I need to know which is the best Java web framework to design an UI. I know some frameworks like

- vaadin
- GWT

Which one is better and faster? And is there anything other than that?

Comment: It depends on the context of the user requirements, that will define the "best" in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see your "what is the best" question will be closed as subjective and argumentative (better ask for the kind of frameworks around and people might give you the pros and cons, but there is never "the best").

You might want to have a look into the [Echo Web Framework](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/).

Comment: Yes, rewording the question would have helped.